# Does the series $\sum{(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n})}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Whats about the given series, Converge or Diverge?
The series is given
$$
\sum_1^\infty{(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n})}
$$

Comment: This is a good example showing the reader that the comparison test may not apply when the general term of a series is negative.

Comment: $$n\geqslant2\implies\frac1{n^2}-\frac1n\leqslant-\frac1{2n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges absolutely and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so what about the sum?

Comment: Please tell me that. 1/n^2 converges because power of n is greater than 1 and 1/n diverge because power of n is equal to 1.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad yeah that is correct

Answer (score 2):

If the series were convergent assume the sum is $l$. This would mean all the terms being positive that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n}=-l+{\pi^2\over 6}$$

But the harmonic series is divergent so the initial series is divergent

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n})}:=\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M}{(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n})}}=\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M}{\frac{1}{n^2}}}-\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{M}{\frac{1}{n}}}=:\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And you know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges. So the initial series also diverges.